# How to parse json array of objects with retrofit which has different data types for same key

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I am getting a json array in API response which has different data types (String, Integer and Array) in same key (**value**) but getting error while parsing them with Retrofit:

```
{
 "custom_attributes": [
    {
      "attribute_code": "description",
      "value": "<p>Product Features:</p>\r\n<ul>\r\n<li>100% cotton</li>\r\n<li>Round neck</li>\r\n<li>Short sleeve</li>\r\n<li>Plastisol printing technique</li>\r\n<li>Small label on side of sleeve</li>\r\n</ul>"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "short_description",
      "value": "<p>100% cotton round neck short sleeve tee with plastisol printing technique</p>"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "category_ids",
      "value": [
          "3",
          "125"
       ]
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "special_price",
      "value": true
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "size",
      "value": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: `retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 4227 path $.custom_attributes[2].value`

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what is the need of keeping your JSON format like this.

According json.org:

JSON is built on two structures:

• A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed list, or associative array.

• An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.

Tell me your requirement i will update your JSON and this problem will be solved once you will start getting updated JSON from erver.

Comment: This response we are getting from [Magento's](https://magento.com/) default API and API team do not want to change or customize that.

Comment: You have to make them change because the format of this JSON is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly store response in string like this

```
   String response =apiresponse;
```

Then try this parsing methood without any thirdparty

get jsonobject from string response

```
JSONObject object=new JSONObject(response);
```

get jsonarray from json object

```
JSONArray jsonArray=object.getJSONArray("custom_attributes");
```

iterate json array till its length

```
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length;i++){

JSONObject newobject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
Boolean valueBoolean;
String valueString;
String attribute_code=newObject.getString("attribute_code");
Object value=newObject.get("value");// get **value** key data in object
```

now check datatype of **value** key

```
if(value instanceof String){
valueString=value.toString(); //if value found string store in in value String 
}else if(value instanceof Boolean){
valueBoolean=(Boolean)value; //if value found Boolean store it in valueBoolean
}

}
```

In the last its upto you , you may simply create a custom arraylist and save all details with datatype key

Comment: Thanks @Umar Ata, I knew this manual parsing, but I want to know if retrofit provides this option or not.

Comment: i don't know about this type of parsing with retrofit but I did it like this , without any errors

Comment: @Pankaj if the need is to receive several types and parse them in the callback, then you'll need to go with what you have been suggested here, and maybe customize it with gson for object parsing